# For Loop, on which partition is Windows. Command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, command-line, cmd

I need to copy some folders from WINDOWS, but OS is not allways in the same partition.
I know now, that it has to be a for loop.

for now i have something like this.

```
for /f %%A in ('%systemdrive% == %%A') do set OS_ROOT=%%A
```

I know that it's false, but have no idea how to make it right.

Comment: Why are you trying to put `%SystemDrive%` into another variable? Why not just use `%SystemDrive%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it doesn't need any stupid for loops.

the right solution is:

```
set OS_ROOT=%systemdrive%
```

it is that simple.

Comment: If you `need to copy some folders from WINDOWS ...`, no, is not that simple, almost, but no. The OS can be installed on different drives, but also in different folders. You need `%systemroot%`

Answer (score 2):

You have an environemt variable taht points to the the installation drive:

```
%SystemDrive%
```

Also windows installation dir:

```
%SystemRoot%
```

or

```
%WinDir%
```